# How to pass parameters from my form action to a view? Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

This is my view function: It takes one kwarg i.e block_id

```
def write_comment(request, block_id):
    block=get_object_or_404(Block, pk=block_id)
    if request.method=='POST':
        form=Comment_form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            #do stuff
        else:
            return render(request,'writers_block/index.html', {'comment_form':form, 'block_form':Block_form()})
```

To access it from my template form I use:

```
{%for block in block_list%}
<form method="post" action="{%url 'write_comment' block_id=block.id%}">
{%csrf_token%}
{{comment_form}}
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
{%endfor%}
```

Somehow I'm always getting a NoReverseMatch saying that write_comment with that arguments is not found:

The urlpattern is:

```
url(r'^write_comment', writers_block.views.write_comment, name='write_comment')
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you change your url like this and try..
       `url(r'^write_comment/(?P<block_id>\d+)/$', writers_block.views.write_comment, name='write_comment')`

Comment: Shouldn't the quotes cover the entire regex? like (r'^write_comment/(?P<block_id>\d+)/$' or should it just cover 'write_comment'

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Btw, do I always to pass parameters through the url?  Is there any way to directly through pass parameters through the template to the view?

Comment: Yes,  the quote should cover up to $. Now i edited correctly.

Comment: You can make block_id as a form field and get it from form data.

Comment: Oh, yeah i could make it a hidden form field and use it. Thanks